# How to add javascript to drupal 7?

Tags: 7, routes, javascript

I found a responsive menu code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/up4nu/149/) and I want to add it to my Drupal 7 site. I have no experience with JavaScript, but I thought that if i just copy the script into mytheme/js/menu.js, call it in mytheme.info, and add the HTML to a block, I will have the script up and running.

The HTML part works fine, but the JavaScript part isn't working.

Why doesn't my JavaScript code work?

Comment: I have checked the provided link and I think, its for single page website. Do you want to create single page website?

Comment: yes, thats what im trying to do. but for some reason the js doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well adding JavaScript can be done through [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

You can add the JavaScript code in your template.php file.

1. Create a cool.js file where you copy the JavaScript code
2. Put the file in your themes/MYTHEME/js folder
3. In your template.php file, create a  page preprocess function

   ```
   function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . "/js/cool.js", array("preprocess" => True));    
   }
   ```
4. Clear the cache
5. Load your page and check the page source code to see if **cool.js** is being loaded; use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to see if the file is present there
6. If the effect is still not coming, then verify the IDs in the HTML are correct

Comment: i tried doing that, and this is what i got upon loading the page:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home2/engeeoco/public_html/sites/all/themes/engeeo/template.php on line 16

Comment: You might have done something wrong in template.php. Please check your template.php code again. Sounds like you have not closed your function with }.

Comment: hihi.. how embarrassing. yes i have no clue in php. anyway, site loads fine now, but still no java effect. you can see it here: engeeo.com

Comment: I dint get you. Do you mean, you corrected the error ?

Comment: i corrected the error, but now the javascript doesnt have any effect

Comment: is the file being loaded ?

Comment: yes: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://engeeo.com/sites/all/themes/engeeo/js/cool.js?mp5k4a"></script>

Comment: then there might be something wrong with the ids in the html tags. Are all tags in the html and js script are matching ?

Comment: i copied the code in its entirety from jsfiddle. maybe you can have a look at my site? engeeo.com. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Singe page website](https://drupal.org/project/single_page_website) module to create single page website in the drupal 7.

You can check [example](http://yaremchuk.ru/) for implementation of the module.

I have also checked your site [engeego](http://engeeo.com/) and I found that there is some javascript issue.

If you include javascript in drupal 7 theme, you need to enclose this into below function.

```
(function($) {

    //your code

})(jQuery);
```